# 三次元空間で直線を引き球との交点を求めたい

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib, numpy

３D空間で直線と球の交点を求めるための直線の式を任意の２点から求め、描写したいのですが、どうプログラミングすればいいですか？
２Dでの直線は式から描写することが可能でした。
３Dでの直線の式は`y = ((x-xp)/a - (z-zp)/c)*b -yp`だと思います。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    x = np.linspace(0,3,4)  # xの値域(0, 1, 2, 3)
    y = x + 1               # 直線の式
    plt.plot(x,y,"r-")      # 直線を引く
    plt.show()              # グラフ表示

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

mpl_toolkitsの中にmplot3dという3D描画用の機能が含まれています。

https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

これを利用して、3Dの球体を `plot_surface` により描画したのち直線を引くというアプローチでいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 球のみの描画まではできています。直線でなく線分でしたら描画も可能でしたが、直線を引くことができない状況です。